# Supervisor of akka doesn't work correctly with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, akka

I'm using akka with Java and Spring. And my main goal is notify other application in a asynchronous way. But sometimes this other app isn't notified. So, I implemented a Supervisor to make use of retries. But, when I receive an Exception, specifically InternalServerErrorException my supervisor does not make another retry. Seems that the RestTemplate and your treatement of exceptions is causing the problem.
Below follows my code:

```
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class NotificacaoSupervisor extends AbstractActor {

    private static final int RETRIES = 5;

    private OneForOneStrategy  ONE_FOR_ONE_STRATEGY = new OneForOneStrategy(
            RETRIES,
            Duration.create("5 minutes"),
            true,
            DeciderBuilder.match(NotificacaoException.class, ex -> SupervisorStrategy.restart())
                      .build());


    @Inject @Qualifier("notifyActor")
    private ActorRef notifyActor;



    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .matchAny(any -> notifyActor.forward(any, getContext()))
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
    return ONE_FOR_ONE_STRATEGY;
    }
}
```

Block that sends a notification

```
try{
       if(content.isPresent()) {
           this.logInfo(content.get());
           HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(content.get(), headers);
           String urlDeCallback = integracao.getUrlDeCallback();
           URI uri = URI.create(urlDeCallback);
           restTemplate.postForObject(uri, entity, Void.class);
       }

} catch (Exception e) {
  this.logError(new ErrorResponse(notificacao).toString(), e);
  throw new NotificacaoException(e);
}
```

Comment: "when I receive an Exception" - Throwing an exception on the client is not the same as receiving a response that an exception occurred on the server. Sounds like `postForObject()` is executing successfully and your server is responding that it failed to process on it's side. If that's the case, you would not have violated the try{} block to cause the custom exception to throw to the Supervisor.

Comment: Hi @Stephan, thanks for reply, so debugging the app after execution of postForObject() it throws an exception and I tried do a workaround throwing another Exception and I put a hook method called postRestart(Throwable t) and it is called multiple  times

Comment: Could it be that you're posting for a void object against a string typed http entity?

Comment: In the other side the method is void, it's the reason because the use of Void an not an mapped object.

Comment: No I mean that `HttpEntity<String>`is not going to map from Void when you post. I think it might need to be `HttpEntity<Void>`